# Openpyxl 2.6.0 save issue

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I have an issue while I try to save an Excel workbook with comments.
Without any comments in the Excel file, there is no issue with my scripts. I simply use:

```
wb_archive = load_workbook(archive_file)
```

However, if the file I want to save has comments, it doesn't work and I have the message:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

So, I open the file with the method:

```
wb_archive = load_workbook(archive_file, keep_vba=True)
```

First run is ok, however, the second one always fails with the error:

> KeyError: "There is no item named 'xl/sharedStrings.xml' in the archive"

Am I wrong somewhere in my code?

```
# coding: utf8
# !/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Program to extract Excel data to an archive
Program Python version 3.5
"""

# Standard Library
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import date

# External Libraries
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Import the interface

# Import the project .py files

filein = "file1.xlsx"
fileout = "file2.xlsx"

def xlarchive(source_file, source_sheet, archive_file, archive_sheet, source_start_line=0, archiving_method="NEW", option_date=False):
    """
    Function to save data from an Excel Workbook (source) to another one (archive).
    Variables shall be check before calling the function.
    :param source_file: file where data are copied from (source)
    :type source_file: Path file
    :param source_sheet: name of the sheet where data are located on the source file
    :type source_sheet: string
    :param archive_file: file where data are copied to (destination)
    :type archive_file: Path file
    :param archive_sheet: name of the sheet where data have to be copied on the destination file
    :type archive_sheet: string
    :param source_start_line:
    :type source_start_line: int
    :param archiving_method: defines if the destination file has to be created
    :type archiving_method: string
    :param option_date: defines if the extraction data shall be recorded
    :type option_date: bool
    :return: None
    """
    wb_source = load_workbook(source_file)
    #keep_vba = true to avoid issue with comments
    ws_source = wb_source.get_sheet_by_name(source_sheet)
    wb_archive = load_workbook(archive_file)
    ws_archive = wb_archive.get_sheet_by_name(archive_sheet)
    if archiving_method == "NEW":
        # index of [archive_sheet] sheet
        idx = wb_archive.sheetnames.index(archive_sheet)
        # remove [ws_archive]
        wb_archive.remove(ws_archive)
        # create an empty sheet [ws_archive] using old index
        wb_archive.create_sheet(archive_sheet, idx)
        ws_archive = wb_archive.get_sheet_by_name(archive_sheet)
    # If extraction has been performed the same day, previous data will be replaced
    # Date are store in Excel under format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.
    # extractiondate is from datetime.now().date() and its format is YYYY-MM-DD
    # Comparison thanks to string is needed
    # As Openpyxl does not enable to delete row, the below code clear data and find the first empty occurrence
    if option_date == True:
        j = 0
        for i in range(ws_archive.max_row, 1, -1):
            if str(ws_archive.cell(row=i, column=1).value)[0:10] == str(date.today()):
                j=j+1
        ws_archive.delete_rows(ws_archive.max_row - j + 1, j)

    for row in ws_source.iter_rows(min_row=source_start_line):
        complete_row = []
        for item in row:
            complete_row.append(item.value)
        if option_date is True:
            complete_row.insert(0, str(date.today()))
        ws_archive.append(complete_row)
    wb_archive.save(archive_file)



xlarchive(filein, "Sheet1", fileout, "Sheet1", option_date=True, archiving_method="False", source_start_line=2)
```